# Cannot connect from python repl to neovim instance which waiting on '127.0.0.1:6666'

Tags: neovim

I tried to experiment with what the nvim documentation (connecting chapter in api.txt) says.
The experiment is to use python repl to execute an instruction to nvim listening for socket communication.

## What I did

I opened TMUX on the terminal and split the pane into left and right.
In the left pane, execute `nvim --listen 127.0.0.1:6666`.
In the right pane, I opened python repl and had it run the following commands in order.

```python
import pynvim
nvim = pynvim.attach('socket', path='127.0.0.1:6666')
nvim.command('echo "Hello"')
```

When I run this code, I get an error in executing the second line of code.
What could be the cause of this?

## Investigation

I ran the `lsof -i :6666` command to confirm that the neovim process is occupying the port.

The following is the error output.

============================================

## Python Repl Output Error

```
import pynvim
nvim = pynvim.attach('socket',path='127.0.0.1:6666')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/user1/.asdf/installs/python/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pynvim/__init__.py", line 111, in attach
    socket_session(path) if session_type == 'socket' else
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/user1/.asdf/installs/python/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pynvim/msgpack_rpc/__init__.py", line 35, in socket_session
    return session('socket', path)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/user1/.asdf/installs/python/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pynvim/msgpack_rpc/__init__.py", line 19, in session
    loop = EventLoop(transport_type, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/user1/.asdf/installs/python/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pynvim/msgpack_rpc/event_loop/base.py", line 93, in __init__
    raise e
  File "/Users/user1/.asdf/installs/python/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pynvim/msgpack_rpc/event_loop/base.py", line 90, in __init__
    getattr(self, '_connect_{}'.format(transport_type))(*args)
  File "/Users/user1/.asdf/installs/python/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pynvim/msgpack_rpc/event_loop/asyncio.py", line 96, in _connect_socket
    self._loop.run_until_complete(coroutine)
  File "/Users/user1/.asdf/installs/python/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/user1/.asdf/installs/python/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 259, in create_unix_connection
    await self.sock_connect(sock, path)
  File "/Users/user1/.asdf/installs/python/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 634, in sock_connect
    return await fut
           ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/user1/.asdf/installs/python/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 642, in _sock_connect
    sock.connect(address)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Welcome to vi SE. Please [edit] and tell us *which* error you receive. Makes it easier for people to help you. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your replay. Friedrich!
I'll add error outpu.